# How to create the CSV file so that its data can be imported to mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I have a big list of cities and I want it to insert in Mysql DB table,

I am looking for a way to create a csv file for those list of cities so that I can import that file in Mysql table....

UPDATE:
I have table structure in my Mysql Table as

```
id, name, IsActive
```

and I have created a csv file which contains values as for example

```
xyz,1
abc,1
sdf,1
```

and so on...

Now when I am trying to import it in my mysql table it prompts me the error message as "Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1"

Please suggest

Comment: Having been a member for nearly 3 years and with 294 questions, **you should know how to ask a good one by now.** What format is your input data in, what have you tried so far, and what language(s) do you want to use to generate the CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Microsoft excel if you want, just put your list of cities into it, organize it the way you want it inserted and then save it as a csv file, here is a link on the matter: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx . If you don't have Microsoft Excel you can download openoffice here: http://www.openoffice.org/download/ you can also do the same with their Excel.